# FactoryGirl Rspec and SQLite3::ConstraintException

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to create a few associated factories, but the Event is NOT working:

**factories.rb**

```
  factory :user, class: User do
    first_name 'John'
    last_name 'Doe'
    email { "#{first_name}.#{last_name}@example.com".downcase } 
    username 'johndoe'
    password 'johndoe'
    password_confirmation 'johndoe'

    association :account_id, factory: :account 
  end

  factory :account, class: Account do
    #id is the only field
  end

  factory :event, class: Event do
    name 'Go to the Dentist'
    start_date "#{Time.now.next_month}"  
    end_date "#{Time.now+1.hour.next_month}" 
    copyright "#{Time.now.year}" 

    association :account_id, factory: :account  
  end
```

**controller_spec.rb**

```
before(:each) do
  @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user_profile, :username => 'johndoe' )
  sign_in @user
  @acct = FactoryGirl.create(:account, :id => @user.account_id)
  @event = FactoryGirl.create(:event, :account_id => @acct.id)
end
```

but this event line is where it all goes awry.  Even if I use @user.account_id to set :account_id for event, it fails with this error:

```
Failure/Error: @event = FactoryGirl.create(:event, :account_id => @acct.id)
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       SQLite3::ConstraintException: constraint failed: INSERT INTO "event" ("account_id", "copyright", "created_at", "deleted", "end_date", "info", "name", "start_date", "type", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
     # ./spec/controllers/controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Thank you very much for any advice you can offer on this!

Comment: One place to check could be the schema file. If there are any constraints specified for the event table (that are not taken care of in the factory), then it might throw a ConstraintException.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason you are getting the constraint exception is that you have already have some data in your tables that conflicts the information you are trying to add.

You probably want to delete all data and then try the rspec test case.

Comment: I have no fixtures or anything in this case.  All I have are these few factories to test against.  How could there be a conflict?

Comment: Well you could have added data into the db via command line testing or something. You can use sqlite browser to see your db.